# What is the write performance of Cassandra, HBase, MongoDB or Elastic Search

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, cassandra, nosql

I was looking for a real test result of write performances of Cassandra, HBase, Mongodb and Elastic Search. I want to collect log data from our servers and this data is really huge. Over 10gb for an hour.

I know everyone is talking about cassandra's write performance and these products have different areas of usage. K/V, Document Oriented or search. But I am insterested in not their storage types right now, only the write performance. for example 50K transactions per second.

Also I want to search on top of this data.

What is your suggestions to handle over 50K trans per second.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cassandra is pretty fast indeed.

[Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/) is very fast too. I know at least one **massive** website that chose it over all other options.

But, really, 50K/sec is nothing special. I did it with MySQL on one machine.

Note, however, that besides how quickly you can write data, you should be also interested in what can you with that data later. Otherwise you can just [pipe all your writes to /dev/null](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs). It will be **insanely** fast.

Also, any "benchmark" you find in the internet is useless. It either uses data with certain characteristics or synthesized data. And this can make all the difference. Nobody will do a benchmark of **your** scenarios, using **your** data, except for **you**.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask how you were able to get 50K/sec on MySQL? What's your hardware configuration?

Comment: @srs2012: RAID10, relaxed transaction flushing (that is, decreased reliability).

Comment: -1 for failing to answer any part of the question whatsoever.

Comment: -1 as this is not an answer expected for the question.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in Netflix's benchmark of Cassandra up to one million writes per second on EC2: http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/11/benchmarking-cassandra-scalability-on.html